# Access WebSQL from native application

Tags: javascript, android, web-sql

I have a hybrid (HTML/JS + Java) application and am using WebSQL database to store data. Is it possible to start a query from Java, execute it in JavaScript and pass a resulting record set back to Java?

Answer (score 1):

Certainly. You can execute any javascript in a loaded `WebView` by loading it as a url:

```
wvwMain.loadUrl( "javascript:document.getElementsByName('save')[0].click();" );
```

(The above invokes a form-element called "save."

Further, you can return anything to native using a [`JavascriptInterface`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Can you please give an example of how to return a record set (data type, etc)?

Comment: Read the documentation, it's very straightforward. You can either return data by using one call per row to a method of the Interface object, or fold the whole thing together by passing JSON strings.